# `command echo` doesn't seem to respect the `echo` arguments

Tags: macos, shell

The `command` utility in Mac OS X which is at version 2.6.0 doesn't seem to honor the arguments passed in for the `echo` command.

If this is a legit bug - can you kindly point me to the project page for this utility. Thanks!

#### Expected

```
$ command echo -e "activate\ndeactivate"
activate
deactivate
```

#### Actual

```
$ command echo -e "activate\ndeactivate"
-e activate\ndeactivate
```

#### Additional Info

```
$ command ls -al
total 3
drwxr-xr-x  13 siva  staff   442 Sep 28 10:52 .
drwxr-xr-x   7 siva  staff   238 Sep 19 14:21 ..
drwxr-xr-x  13 siva  staff   442 Sep 28 10:52 .git

$ command ls -a1 
.
..
.git

$ echo -e "activate\ndeactivate"
activate
deactivate
```

Comment: (btw, `command` just tells the shell to use the external version of a command rather than an alias, function or built-in -- so `command` is part of the shell proper, as opposed to a separate utility).

Comment: You should also consult your `echo(1)` man page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`echo -e` is a nonstandard bash  extension. Not only is it not **required** by the standard, it's not even **allowed** by the standard, which explicitly states that *"Implementations shall not support any options"*.

bash breaks the standard by honoring `-e` as an option (except when both `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are set, in which case it behaves identically to your external `echo` command).

Thus, when you run the external `echo` command provided by your OS vendor, it's an implementation compliant with http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html, and it responds to `-e` by printing the string.

---

As a POSIX-compliant alternative to `echo -e "$foo"`, use `printf '%b\n' "$foo"`.

Comment: Wow, didn't have a clue about this! Where is the documentation regarding the _"Implementations shall not support any options"_?

Comment: It's in the link in the question. Second line of OPTIONS.

Comment: BTW, it's very much worth reading APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections.

Comment: Oh, so, a compliant version of `echo` doesn't support any options?

Comment: Behavior is (explicitly and entirely) undefined by the standard if `-n` is provided, so honoring `-n` is legal but not required. Other than that, correct. Heck, you could legally treat `-e` as an option too, but only if `-n` is also provided (thus freeing an implementation from standard-mandated behaviors).